# Azure AD Oauth 2.0 on Native App

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement to integrate Azure AD to Native App(iOS/Android).
According to the doc, it seems to me that the "Client ID" and "Redirect URI" is storing on the app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-ios

I have an API backend server. So, is that possible that I can handle the OAuth flow on my backend server? So that my app doesn't have to store the "Client ID" and "Redirect URI" locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use client SDK for Mobile Apps to implement authentication. Here is a document for how to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android , you could find documents for other platform on left navigation panel .  With client sdk , you could use [server flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthenticationaadd-authentication-to-your-app) and provide backend app url ,  server flow relies on the identity providers web interface. You could register your app for authentication and configure Azure App Service on azure portal ,please read how to [add authentication to your Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users) . With server flow , you just need to configure your preferred identity provider(azure ad) for backend app and don't need to store  "Client ID" and "Redirect URI" on client side .

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Does this need to host the backend app on Azure App Service? Because we are not hosting our backend on Azure App Service.

Comment: Yes,you need to host the mobile backend app on Azure App Service.